# Gas to propane conversion in old stove

Tags: natural-gas, propane

How do I go about converting this antique gas stove to run on propane? Is it possible?

[image]

Comment: You should be reeeeally careful about doing this; get the air/fuel mix wrong and you might end up making a handy dandy carbon monoxide generator.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how the gas valve or the burners are designed it may be possible to convert to propane fuel. Most conversions are as simple as changing the burner orifices. The orifice is the component that has a miniscule opening that emits the gas just before it ignites. The size of the orifice opening is dependent on the gas being used and how many Btu's are required. Natural gas will have a different sized orifice than propane. One Should not be used with the other.

Look around the gas lines for a small spud like this [orifice spud.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00HTQHOYS) Some spuds come with no openings and can be drilled to a custom opening.